# Validating Text fields in Java not working?

Tags: java, sql, database, validation, netbeans

I am creating an SQL that stores information about customers, and want all the customers to have unique contact numbers, essentially as an identifier for themselves. However my validation for my SQL seems to run even if the number already exists within the SQL, and am unsure of what is going wrong.

```
public static boolean uniqueValidation(String contactNum){
    Connection c = null;                                                                          
    Statement stmt = null;
    boolean result = true;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:custInfo.db"); //this is telling the code where to retrieve the data from that it is looking for.

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT rowid AS isFound FROM CUSTINFO WHERE CONTACTNUMBER LIKE "+contactNum+""; //collecting a rowid from custinfo, if the number is found anywhere
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        String compareString = rs.getString("isFound"); //setting the value from the resultset of rowid to comparestring

        if(!compareString.isEmpty()){ //if there is a value return false
            result = false;
        }else{
            result = true; //else return true as there is no value
        }

        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try `if(rs.next())` .

Comment: It is still continuing to submit information (returning true).

Comment: Do you get any exception message ?

Comment: When i'm using my original code, i get "ResultSet closed", if i use rs.next() i have no exception. I noticed when using debugger also, that when using original it skips over my if statement straight to the catch exception, however with rs.next() it enters the if but returns true rather than false when an identical number has been entered. Possibly an error with my sql search then?

Comment: Note that I meant to replace `if(!compareString.isEmpty())` with `if(rs.next())` , is that what you did ? Also check the part of the code that calls `uniqueValidation`, maybe the problem is there .

Comment: Yeah i replaced that statement.

Comment: The uniqueValidation is just so i am able to call it from a seperate class, it runs correctly fine.